# Symfony2 Two actions in one form

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm learning Symfony2 and here is my problem.

I have created a form with an other one embed in the first one. The thing is I would like to make a submit button for the both part with different actions. I'd like to knonw if it's possible the way I'm trying to do it?

Here is my Form:

```
class creaGrpType extends AbstractType
{
    private $codeEtapeList;

    public function __construct(array $codeEtapeListFromController)
    {
        $this->codeEtapeList = $codeEtapeListFromController;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('codeEtape', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => $this->codeEtapeList,
            'required'  => false))
        ->add('listeStudents', new CreaGrp2Type);

    }
```

and here is my TWIG:

```
<form method="post" {{ form_enctype(formCreaGrp) }}>

    <table>         
                <tr>
            <td>
            {{ form_label(formCreaGrp.codeEtape, "Année d'étude:") }}
                        {{ form_errors(formCreaGrp.codeEtape) }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                        {{ form_widget(formCreaGrp.codeEtape) }}
            <input action = "{{ path('EnsgtiEnsgtiBundle_refreshListe')}}" type="submit" value="Rafraichir la liste des étudiants">
    </form><hr>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <form method="post" {{ form_enctype(formCreaGrp) }}>
            {{ form_label(formCreaGrp.listeStudents, "Choisir les membres du groupe:") }}
            {{ form_errors(formCreaGrp.listeStudents) }}
            {{ form_widget(formCreaGrp.listeStudents) }}
            <input action = "{{ path('EnsgtiEnsgtiBundle_creaGrp2')}}" type="submit"/>
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr><hr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [Embedded Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms) Section of the Symfony2 Book. This explains how to achieve what you are trying to do.